# Text with dynamic values

Tags: dynamic, string-manipulation, text

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{Item[performance, Background -> Red], SpanFromLeft}, {"Congratulations, you passed the assignment with a total performance of 66%.", SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto"}], {{performance, 0}, 0, 100}]
```

I want that the percentage value in the text, change along with the change in manipulate control., i.e., if I manipulate the performance to 66, the text should read 66%.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'change dynamically' that usually assumes some kind of GUI. Do you just want a string that can populate certain values from the entries of the data set? If that's the case you should read the docs for `StringTemplate`.

Comment: I tried StringTemplate, but it doesn't work

Comment: `Manipulate` seems to be crashing MMA for me at the moment, but here's an example with `DynamicModule` :`DynamicModule[{x= 0},
 {Slider[Dynamic[x]], 
  Dynamic[Style[StringTemplate["``"][x], 
    RGBColor[{1 - x, 0, 0}]]]}
 ]`

Comment: Thank You. This works.